# Download multiple files from Firebase in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have several folders in firebase storage that contain images (each folder corresponds to an entity).https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ZpX.png

When I want to download the url of each entity, what firebase does is bring me all the images that it has in the storage even if it does the forEach to each entity.

```
useEffect(() => {
setLoading(true);
Promise.all([getRooms(), getLocation()])
  .then((values) => {
    const roomsSnapshot = values[0];
    const rooms = [];
    const pUrl = [];
    roomsSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const splitAddress = doc.data().address.split(", ");
      formatedAddress.current = splitAddress[1] + " " + splitAddress[0];

    //Download from storage//

      storage
        .ref(`${doc.data().roomPhotoId}/`)
        .list()
        .then(function (result) {
          result.items.forEach((imageRef) => {
            imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              console.log(url)
              roomItems.push(url)

            });
          });
          setRoomsImagesCounter(roomsImagesCounter + 1);
          // no photos scenario
          if (result.items.length === 0) {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        });

      //pushing entity data//

      rooms.push({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
        photosURL: roomItems,
        shortAddress: formatedAddress.current,
        coordsAddress: coords.current,
      });
    });
    console.log(rooms);
    setRooms(rooms);
    // getPhotos(rooms);

    setLoading(false);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error getting getting rooms or user role", err);
  });
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps }, []);
```

I don't know why firebase brings me all the images instead of bringing me the images separately for each entity.

I hope you have understood and I await your answers or any questions you have.

Thanks!

UPDATE

This is the console.log(rooms) https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQkoB.png

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create the storage `ref` like this:

```js
// Create a reference under which you want to list
var listRef = storage.ref().child(`${doc.data().roomPhotoId}/`);

// Find all the prefixes and items.
listRef.listAll()
  .then((res) => {
    res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
      // All the prefixes under listRef.
      // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
    });
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      // All the items under listRef.
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  });
```

Make sure to use `listAll`.

Be aware that:

- root.child('images').listAll() will return /images/uid as a prefix.
- root.child('images/uid').listAll() will return the file as an item.

You can find more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files).

Your code with grouping the downloadURLS:

```js
useEffect(() => {
setLoading(true);
Promise.all([getRooms(), getLocation()])
  .then((values) => {
    const roomsSnapshot = values[0];
    const rooms = [];
    const pUrl = [];
    roomsSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const splitAddress = doc.data().address.split(", ");
      formatedAddress.current = splitAddress[1] + " " + splitAddress[0];

    //Download from storage//

      rooms[`${doc.data().roomPhotoId}`]=[]

      storage
        .ref(`${doc.data().roomPhotoId}/`)
        .list()
        .then(function (result) {
          result.items.forEach((imageRef) => {
            imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              console.log(url)
              roomItems.push(url)

            });
          });
          setRoomsImagesCounter(roomsImagesCounter + 1);
          // no photos scenario
          if (result.items.length === 0) {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        });

      //pushing entity data//

      rooms[`${doc.data().roomPhotoId}`].push({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
        photosURL: roomItems,
        shortAddress: formatedAddress.current,
        coordsAddress: coords.current,
      });
    });
    console.log(rooms);
    setRooms(rooms);
    // getPhotos(rooms);

    setLoading(false);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error getting getting rooms or user role", err);
  });
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tarik but i have de same problem. I think the problem is because of how the roomSnapshot forEach is executed and not because of how they are downloaded, because all the images from all the folders are downloaded and pushed in all entities.

Comment: Could you pls explain a little bit more what result you want to se from your code and what the current one is? Maybe I did not get your problem properly.

Comment: Of course, I bring the rooms entities from the firestore. The images of these entities are in storage.

The useEffect brings the rooms and inside the snapshot.forEach, I want to download the url of the images to push all the data to the room. But when I do the forEach of the itemRef this brings me all the images that are in all the folders in storage storage , it does not separate them by room, which is what should happen if the two forEach worked one inside the other.

I don't know if it is fully understood, but I am not a native English speaker, sorry for that.

Comment: First of all: your english is great! But what I don't understand is that you loop over all rooms get each downloar urls from them and store the data of all rooms in a single Array? That way you get all download urls together in a single array. Do you only need to separate those value sin different arrays or group them in the array?

Comment: ok, that's exactly what I want to do, so there is no way for firebase to bring me only the photos inside the folders. Just download everything you have inside the storage? If you see in the link you can see the folders as they are in storage, and in the code, the doc.data (). RoomPhotoId is the name of each folder.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a solution where each folder urls would be grouped in a nested array in `rooms`